# Unimodular Matrix calculation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix

I know  for a given matrix $M$, there exists a matrix $U$ over the integers with determinant  $+1$ or $-1$ 
such that $UM=E$.  I know $E$, but $M$ is not a square matrix. Is there any easy way to get $U$?

Comment: Could you give us a little more information about the problem, like the dimensions of the matrices? Do the matrices have any properties you might be able to exploit? (Besides $U$, of course.) Also, for my own understanding, $U$ is an integer matrix?

Comment: @Geoff: it looks to me that OP is considering the inverse [Hermite normal form](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermiteNormalForm.html) problem.

Comment: Matrix M is (100, 10). Yes U is an integer matrix.

Comment: Is $E$ a special matrix, i.e., the identity, all ones, tridiagonal ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've thought about this problem a lot, and this answer is the best I can come up with:

Let's suppose that $U$ is a $k \times m$ matrix, $M$ is an $m \times n$ matrix, and $E$ is a $k \times n$ matrix.

If $W$ is an $n \times m$ matrix such that $MW = I$ (in this case, $I$ is $m \times m$), then $U = EW$. Matrices having this property are called *right inverses* of $M$.

The language of generalized inverses can be used to determine right inverses. If both matrices are full rank and $MW = I$, then $M$ and $W$ are $\{1,2\}$-inverses of each other, because $MWM = M$ and $WMW = W$. The best reference that I know of that discussed how to calculate $\{1,2\}$-inverses of matrices is *Generalized Inverses: Theory and Applications, 2nd edition* by Thomas N.E. Greville and Adi Ben-Israel. Unfortunately, the authors don't really have an eye for computational efficiency, so you'll need to tweak their algorithms accordingly.

However, the converse doesn't necessarily hold: if $M$ and $W$ are $\{1,2\}$-inverses and $M$ and $W$ are full rank, $MW$ may not equal $I$. The reasoning is as follows.

If $M$ and $W$ are $\{1,2\}$-inverses, then $MW$ will be a projection matrix with rank equal to $\min\{m,n\}$. $MW$ is an $m \times m$ matrix. These two facts combined means that:

- If $m \leq n$, then $W$ will be a right inverse because $MW = I$.
- If $m > n$, then $W$ will not be a right inverse because $MW$ has rank $n$, and the only full rank projection matrix is the identity matrix.

So the approach of determining a right inverse $W$ using $\{1,2\}$-inverses will only work if $m \leq n$ and $M$ is full rank. Otherwise, a right inverse of $M$ may not exist (there are no guarantees that it will, without imposing properties on $M$).

This doesn't yield a fast algorithm to solve your problem for the matrix dimensions that you've given, but it is at least a partial solution.

Answer (score 6):

You are talking about computation of the Hermite Normal Form (HNF), which is covered in books by [Schrijver](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471982326) and by [Nemhauser and Wolsey](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471359432).    In the theory of lattices and integer matrices, the HNF plays a big role.  It is like an integer QR factorization.

A square integer matrix with determinant $\pm 1$ is called a unimodular matrix.
By Cramer's rule, the inverse of a unimodular matrix is integer and unimodular.  Thus, the unimodular matrices are isomorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}^m$.

Suppose that $M$ is $m \times n$, with linearly independent rows, $m \le n$, and integer entries so that its rows are a basis of a sub-lattice of $\mathbb{Z}^n$. (A lattice in general is the set of integer linear combinations of a set of linearly independent vectors.)

$E$ is the HNF of the lattice determined by the rows of $M$.  It will have an upper triangular form, with the additional property that the first nonzero of each row is bigger than the elements above it.   It is a normal form in the sense that if two lattices are identical, then they have the same $E$, the same HNF.   The HNF can be useful in answering a variety of lattice related questions.  The most basic one is the question of whether a given vector $b$ in $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is in the lattice of $M$'s rows: It is iff $\text{inv}(U)b$ is in the lattice of $E$'s rows, and the triangular structure of $E$ makes this easy to check.

The elements of $E$ and $U$ may be very large integers, and controlling the growth of the elements is the key algorithmic challenge.   If one ignores this, its easy to derive an algorithm by finding a unimodular "Givens" type transformation -- a $2 \times 2$ unimodular transformation that can zero one element of an integer 2-vector.  Integer gcd is a subroutine of the construction of one of these.  With them, one can introduce zeros so as to create the desired upper triangular form.